# Strange CSS behaviour on Chrome for Facebook like box

Tags: css, google-chrome, iframe, facebook-likebox

I am experiencing this strange behaviour on Chrome (I tested both Windows and Linux versions). I also tested it on Firefox but it works properly on that.

I have the Facebook Like Box displaying in a Wordpress side widget. (Its using the official Facebook plugin, although if something is wrong with its output I can easily change it myself). In reality what it does it includes an iFrame.

1. A strange white padding appears underneath the Facebook logo at the bottom of the widget. The strange thing about this is that when I hover over the title, which just changes its colour, the box suddenly adjusts the height to the correct one automatically. You can see it [here](http://www.eve.com.mt/) where the Facebook Like Box widget on the right (3rd box from top) has some white padding. Move the mouse over the 'Like Us?' title and it suddenly adjusts the height to the correct one.
2. A more serious issue occurs when the user navigates to another page, and back to the page. With the page open put another URL in the address bar, such as www.google.com. After it loads just click the 'Back' button of the Chrome browser. You will suddenly see that the Facebook Like Box does not render as before, but it renders in a much shallower box, and ugly scrollbars appear.

What is the reason for this happening? Its the first time I am encountering these strange issues that occur on seemingly unrelated behaviour (hovering a link and clicking back)

Comment: in div.servicebox {
....width: 303px;
height: auto;
overflow: auto;} remove overflow:auto; try this once.

Comment: in div.servicebox {
....width: 303px;
height: auto;
overflow: auto;} remove overflow:auto;(for the second problem)height:280px;(exact height for the 1st problem) try this once.

Comment: @3bu1 If I remove the `overflow: auto` it suddenly flows out of the box, making it even worse. Exact height, yes I can try that but defeats the whole point.

Comment: Unable to replicate this behavior using Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m on Windows 7.

Comment: Also unable to replicate using Safari 5.1.7 so it's likely not a webkit issue.

Comment: @JacquesGoulet I am generating the issue on Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m on Windows 7, and Version 32.0.1700.77 on Ubuntu. Some users also reported the issue. Remember you have to go somewhere else, and then press Back. Yes, could be a Chrome issue. Not sure what is causing it though.

Comment: I did press back, still nothing.

Comment: Do you have any Chrome plugins enabled?  If so try disabling them.

Comment: Absolutely no plugins. Some users also complained of this behaviour. Are you sure you're looking at the right place? I managed to regenerate this easily on 2 browsers (Go to website, type google.com in the URL box, press back, voila Like Us box shows bad)

Comment: I assure you I know how to navigate a browser.

Comment: In Chrome, go to Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Reset Browser Settings.  See if that changes anything.

Comment: @JacquesGoulet Users of the site have complained with the same behaviour, so its not an issue with my browser. I am not saying you don't know how to navigate your browser, I was just asking you whether  you followed the procedure the generate the scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, in your `servicebox` box (that contains the like box) you have a `div` with a class of `serviceheading` that has `float: left;`. I guess this may cause you troubles because the `servicebox` itself does not have any properties to contain floats. You may try adding a [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) solution to `.servicebox` or try adding `overflow: hidden;` as a quick fix. This may solve your first issue.

As far as the second issue is concerned. I would try adding some properties to check if they help.

- make `.fb_iframe_widget` clear the floating logo by `clear: left;` It
  will make this block to always be under the logo.
- make `.fb_iframe_widget` a block element by `display: block;` (right
  now - it is `inline-block`). It will automatically give it the width
  of the parent element (303px)
- make the following selector `.fb_iframe_widget iframe` and add
  `max-width: 100%;` to it. These styles will make sure the `iframe`
  does not get bigger - so the scrolling buttons will *probably*
  disappear.

Hope it will help.

**UPDATE**

For some reason when the back button is pressed the `<span>` inside the `.fb_iframe_widget` was getting set to height and width of 0px. The following solves the issue, although its a bit of hack and the height and width had to be hardcoded:

```
.fb_iframe_widget iframe
{
    height: 230px !important;
    width: 300px !important;    
}

.fb_iframe_widget span
{
    height: 230px !important;
    width: 300px !important;    
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution. The first issues seems to have been solved. The second one is still an issue though. The scrollbars did disappear now, but the box now appears empty.

Comment: Hm, what if you try adding the min-height property to the widget? Will you see the iframe?

Comment: Nope, it just displays the empty widget box. You can see it for your self if you like, its with the above settings you suggested. In chrome you can then just do 'Inspect Element' and add a `height` or `min-height` property, the box will increase height but it will just be an empty white box. The weirdest thing in all this is why is it happening when pressing the 'Back' button!

Comment: I think there is a difference between adding the `min-height` after the page load and before it. Try adding it to the stylesheet and then test the Back-button bug

Comment: Tried it, you can see it now. It just displays an empty box with the min-height. Still the Facebook widget contents don't display when you press the back button :(

Comment: It seems that what is happening is that the Chrome is setting the height and width of the `iframe` to 0px. I tried to set it explicitly and also put `!important` as follows: `.fb_iframe_widget iframe { height: 230px !important; width: 300px !important; }` but it is still being set to 0px

Comment: Finally! I managed to fix it. Still don't know why it was happening, but at least its solved now. I added the following: `.fb_iframe_widget span { height: 230px !important; width: 300px !important;  }` and now it is working fine!

Comment: I added the solution that worked for me so that I accept your solution as the right one.